# Returning fontsize and font family from QFontDialog PyQt

Tags: python, pyqt4, qfont

Is there a way to return the font size and font name from `QFontDialog`? I'm new on `python` and all the examples I have seen do not return the font name and/or font size.

What I have now it's something like this:

```
def font_picker(self, button, line):
  font, ok = QtGui.QFontDialog.getFont()

  if ok:
     button.setFont(font)
     line.setFont(font)
```

But I don't know how to return `fontsize` as a `float` and `fontfamily` as a `string`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [QFont](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qfont.html) object itself has `pixelSize`, `pointSize` and `pointSizeF` for getting the size. It has `family` for getting the font family.

```
 if ok:
     button.setFont(font)
     line.setFont(font)
     return font.pointSizeF(), font.family()
```